# What does this expression do in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$_ = ~m [($substr)]g;
```

I have three questions:

1. What's the difference between `~m[]` and `~m//`?
2. Why if deleted `()` the results would be different?
3. What does it mean by the `g` at the end?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no difference between `/.../`, `m/.../` and `m[...]`. You can use the delimiter of your choice when you specify the `m`. `/.../` is standard, but sometimes it's more readable to use something else. For example, compare

   ```
   /^http:\/\//
   ```

   with

   ```
   m[^http://]
   ```
2. `()` are captures. They capture the text matched by the pattern within. You can access the captured text of the first capture via `$1`, the second via `$2`, etc. In list context, the match operator returns the captured strings.

   ```
   $ perl -E'say for 'abcd' =~ /(.).(.)/;'
   a
   c
   ```
3. `m//g` is used to find all the matches. `m//` is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

   ```
   $ perl -E'say for "abc" =~ /(.)/;'
   a

   $ perl -E'say for "abc" =~ /(.)/g;'
   a
   b
   c
   ```

Note that `$var = ~m[...]` and `$var =~ m[...]` are very different, and that you surely meant to use the latter. `=~` followed by a match operator specifies the variable against which the match operator is matching.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `~m[]` and `~m//` are same, and they are boundary symbols.
2. Scalar variable `$substr` is embed into parentheses, it means that you can get     matched value into parentheses through print `$1`.
3. The symbol `g` means global match.